# Can't dynamic resize IMG after javascript dynamic content load

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, dynamic

I use this javascript from dynamicdrive to load content into a div:

```
    var bustcachevar=1 //bust potential caching of external pages after initial request? (1=yes, 0=no)
    var loadedobjects=""
    var rootdomain="http://"+window.location.hostname
    var bustcacheparameter=""

    function ajaxpage(url, containerid){
        var page_request = false
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
        page_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        else if (window.ActiveXObject){ // if IE
            try {
                page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
            catch (e){
                try{
                    page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                catch (e){}
            }
        }
        else
        return false
        page_request.onreadystatechange=function(){
            loadpage(page_request, containerid)
        }

        if (bustcachevar) //if bust caching of external page
        bustcacheparameter=(url.indexOf("?")!=-1)? "&"+new Date().getTime() : "?"+new Date().getTime()
        page_request.open('GET', url+bustcacheparameter, true)
        page_request.setRequestHeader('charset', 'ISO-8859-1')
        page_request.send(null)
    }

    function loadpage(page_request, containerid){
        if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1))
        document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText
    }
```

I use a self written php function called "displayImage('url','width')" to display an image which is then dynamically re-sized to the specified width.

This works great on static content, however, the function refuses to work on dynamic content.

Can anyone give me a push in the right direction on this one? :/ I'm not so good at javascript...

EDIT:

Sorry, forgot to add the php function, here it goes:

```
function displayImage($img_path, $height) {
$image_info = getimagesize($img_path);  
$new_dimension = imageResize($image_info[0], $image_info[1], $height);
$returnstr = "<IMG SRC=\"{$img_path}\" " . $new_dimension . "/>\n";
return $returnstr;
}

function imageResize($width, $height, $target) {
if ($width > $height) {
$percentage = ($target / $width); 
} else {
$percentage = ($target / $height);
}
$width = round($width * $percentage);
$height = round($height * $percentage);

return "width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\"";
```

}

Comment: I don't see any image-resizing functionality at your code.

Comment: I'll add it right now, hold on..

Comment: It's added, sorry it took so long but something needed my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language, which means it creates the page, sends it to the browser and that's it. It can't resize the images you add to the page later. You have either to to JS to do that, or use that PHP function in the ajax page itself, and dynamically load already reduced images. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know too much JS, but if I were to proceed, using this php function in the ajax page itself... How do you recommend I proceed? Because, I've already included the script in the page that's loaded using ajax, but it didn't do much, but I don't know if that is what you mean by 'using the php function in the ajax page itself'... i.e. I don't know how to shrink the images first, using the php script, and then loading the page using ajax call. (eventualy if I try enough I'd be succesful but tips are welcome).

Comment: Just never give up. What I meant is to include the shrinking script into the file you're calling with ajax, so that ajax sends you images that are good to go (no further shrinking needed).

Comment: Thnx for the help. My problem was in the SRC tag of the IMG. had to use '../folder/imagename.png' instead of './folder/imagename.png' for it to work with the script included in the page that's being dynamically loaded. ^_^'

Comment: No problem, glad you've fixed it! Most of the times it's best to avoid using relative paths ('../') and use absolute ('http://site.com/etc/' or just '/etc/').